# How create dynamic row in pdfMake table

Tags: javascript

I’ve JavaScript Array of Objects, which look like as follows

```
arr=[[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[3,5,6],[2,4,5]]
```

How to remove outer array from the same. The expected output mentioned below.

Based on the output, I want to create a table in `pdfMake`.The splitted array used to create dynamic rows on the table.

```
[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[3,5,6],[2,4,5]
```

Comment: The "expected output" is not a JavaScript data structure.

Comment: That's an array of arrays, not an array of objects.

Comment: makes no sense.... why would you remove the outer array? it would not be valid....

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the outer array"? What do you want to end up with?

Comment: the expected output is invalid JavaScript

Comment: Of what type do you expect the variable, holding the elements no longer in the array, to be?

Comment: In case You need a string in the end You can do this with `map()` and `join()` methods: `arr.map(x => \`[${x}]\`).join(',')`

Answer (score 2):

Note that although arrays are objects, most people would call what you have an array of *arrays*, rather than an array of objects.

You can't remove that outer layer unless you have multiple variables or properties or similar to put the result in. Your result is *multiple* things, so you need a container for them (an array, an object, a `Map`, ...).

If you *do* have variables or similar to assign them to, you could use destructuring:

```
const arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[3,5,6],[2,4,5]];
const [a, b, c, d] = arr;
console.log(a); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Live Example:

```js
const arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[3,5,6],[2,4,5]];
const [a, b, c, d] = arr;
console.log(a); // [1, 2, 3]
```

But you have to know in advance how many there are. If it's dynamic, you want...a container, like an array, or an object, or a `Map`.